# Python Name Generator

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm trying to pull a random name from the 'name' column and a lastname from the 'lastName' column based on the data I extracted from the sqlite3 table. But only one letter appears on the screen output. Where am I making a mistake?

Here is the code I have tried so far.

```
import sqlite3
import random
def randomTable():

   connection = sqlite3.connect("00nameGenerator.db") 

   cursor = connection.execute("""select * from Name order by random() limit 1""")

   for row in cursor:
       print("Name = "+random.choice(row[1]) + " "+ random.choice(row[2]))
       print()
   connection.close()
randomTable()
```

Comment: you should remove limit 1

Comment: @MohitGhodasara and how would this fix the issue actually ?

Answer (score 1):

`row[1]` returns a string (the second column from the table). `random.choice(row[1])` will return a random character/letter from that string.

Same goes for `row[2]` and `random.choice(row[2])`.

Comment: There is an id in row [0] in the sqlite3 database table. So I wrote row [1] and row [2]. I want the data in the table rather than the character.

Comment: @SongJiHyo The problem is with you doing `random.choice(row[1])` instead of simply `row[1]`, not with `1` instead of `0`